# Defined `inline` Template Method Isn't Found for Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, methods, template-specialization

Consider the following minimal example:

```
template <int A> struct Foo {
    inline Foo();
};
template <> struct Foo<1> {
    inline Foo();
};

template <int A>
inline Foo<A>::Foo() {}

int main() {
    Foo<2> okay;
    Foo<1> fail; //<- Compile warn/error here!  Why?
}
```

As you can see, I define a `struct Foo` and make a full specialization of it.  Then, I define the interior method.

When I construct `okay`, it calls `Foo<2>::Foo()`, taking the definition I gave.  However, when I try to construct `fail`, it tries to call `Foo<1>::Foo()`, and *this doesn't work* (prints compile warning, link fails).  **Why does this happen?**

---

<sup>Outputs of various compilers, for your convenience:

• GCC 7.2.0: *warning: inline function 'Foo<1>::Foo()' used but never defined*

• Clang 5.0.0: *warning: inline function 'Foo<1>::Foo' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]*

• ICC 17 [works happily]

• MSVC 2017 [works happily]</sup>

Comment: You need to define `Foo<1>::Foo` separately.

Comment: `inline Foo<1>::Foo() {}` you need this explicitly defined too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because you didn't define it. A full specialization of a class template essentially produces a "regular" class definition. You can add, omit or modify the members of the class.

What it also means is that it doesn't get anything from the primary template "automagically". You need to provide it explicitly. And since you didn't provide

```
inline Foo<1>::Foo() {} // Note how we don't need template<> here? Like a regular class
```

There is no such c'tor.

As for the "works happily" addendum you posted, it doesn't matter. When you don't define an entity that is used by your program, it's a violation of the one definition rule. Formally, your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required. Which means the behavior is undefined, and implementations are free to mess with your compiled program as they see fit.

Be thankful the better compilers of the bunch let you know you messed up, instead of gliding over the issue.

Comment: I think I (at least nearly) get it, although I'm struggling to find a good _reason_ for it. I don't see why `Foo<1>` being a separate class definition means it can't pull a definition from a template, if that definition fits. Is it because `Foo<A>` might have some method `::fooify()` that `Foo<1>` lacks, and if you could pull fitting definitions, one could have `Foo<1>::fooify()` even though that was never declared? Or what's the rationale?¶ As for "works happily", I regularly compile my code in 4 different configurations × the 4 compilers listed, exactly to discover discrepancies like this.

Comment: @imallett - Think `std::vector<bool`. For a specialization like *that* to work properly, nothing *can* be pulled in automatically.

Comment: Sure. Which means the programmer has to specialize all the methods, just as specialize the class itself.

Comment: @imallett - There's stuff in vector beyond the public interface. Private functions, implementation details. Those are a bigger problem. It's easier to just exclude everything, and have programmers pull correct things **in**, than to come up with a way to let programmers keep a whole lot of wrong things **out**.